# Could not execute mockbuild: Could not download sources

Tags: fedora, rpm, packaging, rpm-spec

When writing a .spec file for Fedora, I ran into a problem. I can't seem to be able to do `fedpkg mockbuild` at all. No matter what source I use, HTTPS or local, I keep running into this error:

```
Failed to get repository name from Git url or pushurl
Failed to get ns from Git url or pushurl
Could not execute mockbuild: ('Could not download sources: %s', AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'"))
```

What's going on? The relevant part of my .spec file:

```
Name:           purple-telegram-tdlib
# The main maintainer has not merged #154 for TDLib 1.8.0
Version:        0.8.1-BenWiederhake
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        New libpurple plugin for Telegram

License:        GPLv2
URL:            https://github.com/ars3niy/tdlib-purple
Source0:        tdlib-purple-BenWiederhake-master.zip

BuildRequires:  gcc-c++
BuildRequires:  git
BuildRequires:  make
BuildRequires:  cmake
BuildRequires:  tdlib-devel == 1.8.0
BuildRequires:  tdlib-static == 1.8.0
BuildRequires:  libpurple-devel
BuildRequires:  libwebp-devel
BuildRequires:  libpng-devel
BuildRequires:  gettext-devel
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the character `-` in the version. According to the [specification](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/spec.html):

> The version string consists of alphanumeric characters, which can optionally be segmented with the separators ., _ and +, plus ~ and ^ (see below).
>
> Tilde (~) can be used to force sorting lower than base (1.1~201601 < 1.1). Caret (^) can be used to force sorting higher than base (1.1^201601 > 1.1). These are useful for handling pre- and post-release versions, such as 1.0~rc1 and 2.0^a.

Don't confuse the tilde (`~`) for the dash (`-`)! The dash is not a valid character. In this case, you should be using `^` instead, like so:

```
Version:        0.8.1^BenWiederhake
```

It builds after that change.